# Return statement not rendered

Tags: html, django, templates

my HTML code

```
<select class="custom-select" id="lab" name="lab" onchange="toggleLabs(this);" required >
                                  <option value="no">No Lab Choosen</option>
                                  <option value="newlab" id="newlab">New Lab</option>
                                  {% for lab in all_obj %}
                                  <option value='{{lab.lab_name}}'  onclick="myFunc()">{{lab.lab_name}}</option>
                                  {% endfor %}
                              </select>
```

javascript:
 where I'm accessing the selected option and passing it to the views.py

```
 function toggleLabs(select){
iden_lab=select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("", url:'/listlabs(idenlab)',{slab: iden_lab}, function (data) {
        alert(iden_lab);
    });
});
```

my views.py where I'm rendering it back

```
def listlabs(request,):
all_obj = labs.objects.all()
val = labs.objects.all(lab_name)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = create_lab()
    if request.is_ajax():
        lab_selected = request.GET['slab']
        obj_val = labs.objects.filter(lab_name=lab_selected).values('lab_name')[0]
        print(obj_val)
        val = obj_val['lab_name']
        print(val)
        return render(request, 'listlabs.html/', {'form': form, 'all_obj': all_obj, 'val': val})

else:
  form = create_lab(request.POST)
  return HttpResponse('success')
return render(request, 'listlabs.html/', {'form': form ,'all_obj': all_obj,'val': val})
```

I wanted `val` to render only if I go to the `If` part.
I tried printing to check if it comes inside the if block.
It printed the value in my command prompt, but the return statement is not rendered.

only the last return statement is rendered, in which my `val` hasn't been overwritten,

How do I fix this? Why isn't my return statement working?

Thank You.

Comment: You realize that a template is rendered at *server side*, and thus when you click the button, then all the variables in the template no longer exist. You can not do it that way, you need JavaScript to change values interactively, like Angular, or some custom JavaScript, etc.

Comment: you can pass that selected value to views and get back to template and make it select or you can use session storage

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem   i've not given any form action to specify that.and while rendering the template from the server,i've sent a list of all objects,and once i get a hold of this,i've used a for loop to check what is the value of var and i will print only that from the list

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza yes,i tried that using ajax call,but it failed to work

Comment: @KavyaMani i dont understand why you used Ajax. use below given code.post the form from form view itself return the value and select it

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza hey! I don't need so much to access the variable selected.       
  I'm accessing the value in java script using the following : iden_lab=select.options[select.selectedIndex].text; 
And I'm sending it to the views using:

$(document).ready(function () {
        $.get("", url:'/listlabs(idenlab)',{slab: iden_lab}, function (data) {
            alert(iden_lab);
        });
    });

Comment: My views.py

def labs(request):
obj=labs.objects.all()
         if request.is_ajax():
                 lab=request.GET['slab']
                 obj=labs.objects.filter(name=lab).values('name')[0]
                  extracted_name=obj['name']
                  return render(request,'list.html',{'ext': extracted_name})
         else:
              do something
              return HttpResponse("helo")

return render(request,'list.html' ,{'obj':obj})

The problem I'm facing is, The render of if is not working,but when i print value of extracted_name, it appears on my cmd

Comment: please update your question and updated all code base

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza yea,  I shall do it.I'm new to this and hence I didn't know where to post this.Thanks.

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza I've updated the question.

Comment: are you using form to post?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def listlabs(request,):
all_obj = labs.objects.all()
val = labs.objects.all(lab_name)
form = create_lab()
if request.is_ajax():
    lab_selected = request.GET['slab']
    obj_val = labs.objects.filter(lab_name=lab_selected).values('lab_name')[0]
    print(obj_val)
    val = obj_val['lab_name']
    print(val)
    return render(request, 'listlabs.html/', {'form': form, 'all_obj': all_obj, 'val': val})

else:
    form = create_lab(request.POST)
    return HttpResponse('success')
return render(request, 'listlabs.html/', {'form': form ,'all_obj': all_obj,'val': val})
```